# varnish 503s when accessing backend

Tags: varnish

I have two backends that I'm serving on my web server, both of them are remotely hosted by third party companies. One of them is a support portal page, which is passing cookies and I suspect is causing the page to not load. I see varnish pass the request along to the backend, but when the request hits the backend I see the following response:

```
14 FetchError   c http read error: 0
15 BackendClose b support
14 VCL_call     c error
```

Details of my VCL settings, runtime parameters and full log output can be found on my gist page: https://gist.github.com/4321241. Is there something that's not allowing the cookies to pass through or get cut off somehow? Is there a more permissive "pass" rule that I can put in place to rule this out?

Answer (score 0):

Varnish does not support HTTPS.